# Running kafka server throws NoClassDefFoundError exceptions

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am getting lot of NoClassDefFoundError in a running Kafka server. I am not sure what is causing this? Has anyone else faced this issue?

I am using Kafka v2.1.1 and Java 11. I recently upgraded to v2.1.1

Update:
Note that I am seeing this exception in only 2 brokers out of the 5 in entire cluster.

Exception 1:

```
[2019-02-28 00:54:49,288] INFO Successfully authenticated client: authenticationID=rajputs/hostbased@UNIX.DESHAW.COM; authorizationID=rajputs/hostbased@UNIX.DESHAW.COM. (org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslServerCallbackHandler)
[2019-02-28 00:54:49,469] ERROR [KafkaApi-4] Error when handling request: clientId=consumer-2, correlationId=1686, api=METADATA, body={topics=[fps.rajputs.jpse.desim_se],allow_auto_topic_creation=true} (kafka.server.KafkaApis)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/immutable/SortedMap$$anon$1
        at scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap.filterKeys(SortedMap.scala:87)
        at scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap.filterKeys$(SortedMap.scala:87)
        at scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap.filterKeys(TreeMap.scala:46)
        at kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer.$anonfun$getMatchingAcls$1(SimpleAclAuthorizer.scala:245)
        at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:251)
        at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inReadLock(CoreUtils.scala:257)
        at kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer.getMatchingAcls(SimpleAclAuthorizer.scala:233)
        at kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer.aclsAllowAccess$1(SimpleAclAuthorizer.scala:154)
        at kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer.authorize(SimpleAclAuthorizer.scala:159)
        at kafka.server.KafkaApis.$anonfun$authorize$1(KafkaApis.scala:371)
        at kafka.server.KafkaApis.$anonfun$authorize$1$adapted(KafkaApis.scala:371)
        at scala.Option.forall(Option.scala:247)
        at kafka.server.KafkaApis.authorize(KafkaApis.scala:371)
        at kafka.server.KafkaApis.$anonfun$handleTopicMetadataRequest$1(KafkaApis.scala:970)
        at kafka.server.KafkaApis.$anonfun$handleTopicMetadataRequest$1$adapted(KafkaApis.scala:970)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$partition$1(TraversableLike.scala:313)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Set$Set1.foreach(Set.scala:95)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike.partition(TraversableLike.scala:313)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike.partition$(TraversableLike.scala:311)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.partition(Traversable.scala:104)
        at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handleTopicMetadataRequest(KafkaApis.scala:970)
        at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handle(KafkaApis.scala:109)
        at kafka.server.KafkaRequestHandler.run(KafkaRequestHandler.scala:69)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Exception 2:

```
[2019-02-28 01:05:58,920] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=4] Removed 0 expired offsets in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-02-28 01:06:04,296] WARN Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 4002ms for sessionid 0x468d0a6602700cc (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2019-02-28 01:06:04,296] INFO Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 4002ms for sessionid 0x468d0a6602700cc, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2019-02-28 01:06:04,972] INFO Client will use GSSAPI as SASL mechanism. (org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient)
[2019-02-28 01:06:04,972] INFO Opening socket connection to server mwkafka-zk-test-03.dr/10.218.247.19:2181. Will attempt to SASL-authenticate using Login Context section 'Client' (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2019-02-28 01:06:04,973] INFO Socket connection established to mwkafka-zk-test-03.dr/10.218.247.19:2181, initiating session (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2019-02-28 01:06:04,973] WARN Session 0x468d0a6602700cc for server mwkafka-zk-test-03.dr/10.218.247.19:2181, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/zookeeper/proto/SetWatches
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.primeConnection(ClientCnxn.java:929)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:363)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1145)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.zookeeper.proto.SetWatches
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 3 more
```

Comment: I guess sth are missed or some mismatched versioning happened. Pls check if the tar file you've downloaded from Kafka site is complete? You can check using the md5 or sha tools.

Comment: I am using the same tarball in for all the brokers but these exceptions show up only in 2 brokers out of the 5.